# What does the padlock mean on .zip files

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

sometimes when i create .zip files by right clicking on a file/folder and going to Send to > Compressed (zipped) folder there is a small padlock on the icon

i can open it easily enough however i am wondering what it means and if it could prevent the .zip file being opened up on other computers as i do this to zip up soundtracks i rip and tag with album art in case if i need them on another computer

Comment: Sometimes?  I haven't seen this, can you replicate and show a screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [padlock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2u3EU.png) means that you have a [private item in a non-private directory](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/12/09/9934348.aspx).

Your zip file has permissions which are more restrictive than the directory in which it's saved. These relate to the file itself not to zip compression.